# How to count a certain number of clicks javascript?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I want to find out how you count a certain number of clicks using onclick in javascript?
Here is my code:

```
<script>
var test= 1;

function myFunction(){
document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML= test;
test++;

}
</script>
```

I want to know how you can stop this code when it reaches 25 clicks?
That would be very helpful thanks.

Comment: Define "stop this code". Check to see if it's 25 or above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If test is below 25 execute what's inside the if statements if not don't do anyhing.

```
<script>
var test= 1;

function myFunction(){
   if(test < 25){
       document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML= test;
       test++;
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a an example with sample code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var test = 1;

            function myFunction() {
                if (test < 25) {
                    document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = test;
                    test++;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="MyDiv" onclick="myFunction()">
            Click me!!
        </div>
        <div id="hello">
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```